# Null-including search in Postgresql using single placeholder

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, where-clause, sql-null

Having a table

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (x int)
INSERT INTO t VALUES (null), (0) ,(42)
```

And query with **two** placeholders:

```sql
SELECT x FROM t WHERE x = ? OR x IS NULL AND ? IS NULL
```

The logic is the following: if I resolve those placeholders with `42` it returns `42`. If I resolve them with `null` it returns `null`. In other words, it is a null-including search.

The question is:

Is it possible to rewrite this query (in Postgresql) to have a single placeholder `?` instead of two?

Comment: `x is not distinct from ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres implements null-safe equality through [operator `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#id-1.5.8.8.15.1), which is exactly what you ask for.

So:

```
SELECT x FROM t WHERE x IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder for parameters in PostgreSQL is `$1`, `$2`, etc.  Letting you use `?` instead is something some drivers implement for convenience, but they do offer less flexibility.

Using the real notation, you can specify one parameter to occur in more than one place:

```
SELECT x FROM t WHERE x = $1 OR x IS NULL AND $1 IS NULL
```

This has the advantage over IS NOT DISTINCT FROM in that it can use an index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use `is not distinct from` and only use one placeholder:

```
where x is not distinct from ?
```

`is distinct from`/`is not distinct from` are `null`-safe comparison operators that treat `null` as a "real" value for comparison purposes (so `null = null` for instance).